# Is there any Callback that gives me feedback about lost packages in Twilio beta8 SDK?

Tags: android, twilio

I'm developing an app in Android that uses Twilio to communicate through VoIP the users. I´m using beta-8 of the Voice SDK. My problem is that the call sometimes goes to "black" and you can´t hear anything from one side or another. This is because of the network, because I have been monitoring this.

My question is if there is some way to know when this is happening to notify the App and inform the user that we are trying to reconnect the call with some layout.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is almost a way to do this.

We have a [Voice Insights Dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-insights/voice-insights-dashboard) right now, which you can enable in your account and see account reports for your calls.

In the latest JavaScript Twilio Client you can also get [call quality events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-insights/call-quality-events-twilio-client-sdk). However this is still under development for Android and iOS Clients.

So, the overall answer is: not yet, but it's being developed so keep an eye on the [Twilio blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/) for announcements.